# Evolution of the meaning of Tollere?

Tags: etymology

One of my favorite Latin words is [Tollere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tollo) because it means both "to raise" as in to lift off the ground, as well as (more poetically) "to raze" or destroy/take away.

Are there any commentaries on how this word came to have seemingly disparate meanings?

Comment: All of the etymologies on the linked page are related to lifting / carrying, I'm particularly interested in where the "to destroy" came from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually amazingly simple.

To raise > to raise up from its place > to remove > to destroy by removing > to destroy

The visual metaphor here is astounding: imagine you want to topple a temple. What better way to do so than by uprooting from its foundations the columns upon which the temple depends? If you remove the columns, the temple is destroyed.

*Auferre* works on the same principle, though that shouldn't be surprising since the perfect principle parts of *ferre* is the old perfect principle parts of *tollere* (and why *tollere* has the *sus-* instead)!

Comment: Excellent. I had thought it would be something simple, but I have never been able to reconcile the visual metaphor. Unlike _altus_ where it's both high and deep because it's conveying a meaure of "great vertical distance".

Comment: I watched *San Andreas* yesterday (for those of you not in the US or not familiar with pop culture, it was a terrible disaster movie that came out last year) and was reminded that buildings can often survive earthquakes that cause them to sway from side to side, but that when they get tossed 10 feet up in the air only to drop to earth again, they're basically toast.